# C#: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'WebBrowser'

Tags: c#, listbox, browser

Hello I am working with my web browser and I keep getting the following error: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'WebBrowser'.

What I am trying to do with my code is loop through every item in a listbox, visit a page, make a message box saying success popup, then move down to the next item. What happens is it only says 'Success' for the first two items then it stops working for the third and when I close down my program I get the error/warning listed above.

This is my code:

```
listBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < listBox3.Items.Count; i++)
{
     completed();
     move();
}
```

This is the code for the completed():

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());

while (!(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete))
{
    Application.DoEvents();

    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
}
```

This is the code for the move():

```
listBox3.SelectedIndex = +1;

webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());

while (!(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete))
{
    Application.DoEvents();

    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
}
```

And I get the error in this line:

```
if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to access `webBrowser1`, but it's been disposed of since it's no longer needed by the form. You can protect against this by checking for `webBrowser1.IsDisposed` and exiting the loop if it is, after `Application.DoEvents()`, like so:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());

DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

while(webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
    Application.DoEvents();

    if(webBrowser1.IsDisposed || DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds > 10.0) break; // A time limit of 10 seconds, can be changed

    if(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
}
```

Also, I can't say for certain since I don't have the entire code, but... a loop is very inefficient there. It will hog CPU cycles doing nothing. A better solution might be to handle the `WebBrowser`'s `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, your code stopped the error but I still have the issue of the listbox not moving one up after it saying Success on the second item.

Comment: @user1017524: Have you examined the response? You may need to break out of the loop if a certain time limit is passed.

Comment: Nope :/. Im not sure how to break out of the loop after a time limit. Also, would there be a more efficient way to run this in the documentcompleted event but still get it to iterate down and browse the sites?

Comment: @user1017524: You can have it in a stack, I'll make a demo soon. As for breaking out after a time limit, I've edited my answer to add that.

Comment: Thanks again. Also, Ive examined the code and somehow this line of code:  listBox3.SelectedIndex = +1; only gets executed once. That sort of explains why it says 'Success' for the first two but not anything afterwards. Do you know how to make it keep +1'ing the listbox? I tried a foreach, for loop, even no loop and still nothing :/

Comment: @user1017524: I was wondering about that :) That line of code is the same as saying `listBox3.SelectedIndex = 1`. The `+` doesn't change anything. You want `listBox3.SelectedIndex += 1` or `listBox3.SelectedIndex++`.

Comment: Woah! It worked! Thanks a ton :D. Oh now my only issue is with this: 'listBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;for (int i = 0; i < listBox3.Items.Count; i++) {completed();listBox3.SelectedIndex += 1;
}' After its done with the iteration I get an error in the +1: **InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex**

Comment: @user1017524: It's because that's the number of items in the listbox. Start by setting `listBox3.SelectedIndex = 0` before your loop and it should work.

Comment: @user1017524: Oops :P Okay, you should check `if(i < listBox3.Items.Count - 1) listBox3.SelectedIndex += 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the navigation never completes on the third item, so you are stuck in your loop. When you close the form down, the loop is still going, but at some point, .net cleans up the form and your webbrowser1 element is no longer valid.

So, you need to introduce some additional code to:

1) Break out of your loop after a specified period of time (1 minute) and indicate failure.

2) If the form shuts down, break out of the loop (you can add a form-level property that is set in the Form.Closing or Form.Closed event and if this is true, break out of the loop).

Comment: Maybe this is nitpicking, but it doesn't have anything to do with .NET's garbage collector, per se. The garbage collector will finalize and/or free objects from memory when it detects there are no longer any references to them. That isn't the case here.

Comment: A little :). But it is better to have the answer be completely correct. Updated the answer.